# cudaMemcpy double array to float array

Tags: cuda

Is there any way to copy double array from Host to the float array on Device. I am not concerned with loss of precision?
I have next case:

```
double* host = new[N];
... // Perform some calculations on host array

float* device;

cudaMalloc( (void**) &device, N * sizeof(float) );
cudaMemcpy( device, host, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

When trying above written code I was getting error invalid argument.
Is there any solution to this besides changing host array to float?

Comment: I am not sure you understand what memcpy or cudaMemcpy does. It does byte-to-byte binary copy without considering precision of float or double. So even if you run the code and you don't get any error, you will have garbage in device vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` is 4 bytes, `double` is 8 bytes. You can't simply `memcpy` between incompatible types, you must first convert the `double`s to `float`s.

Something like this (I took the liberty of replacing your raw arrays with standard library constructs):

```
std::vector<double> host_double(N); 
// Perform some calculations on host array

// Make a copy of the host vector, converting all doubles to floats
std::vector<float> host_float(host_double.begin(), host_double.end());

// The rest is almost unchanged
float* device;

cudaMalloc((void**)&device, N * sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(device, host_float.data(), N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

However, are you sure you are benefiting from the usage of `double` at all? The highest precision of all your computation chain will be the one of `float` anyway.

Comment: Its a nasty thing to do, but it might be the only way. I am not, but project is huge and it is written using doubles only even though float precision is just fine.